# WPF Setter Value inlining

Tags: wpf

I have this code:

```
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
    <Setter.Value>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The application starts correctly, but it's verbose.

I tried to inline my code, so I wrote this:

```
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome"
        Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}"/>
```

But now if I run the application, it doesn't start. Why?

Comment: Does it work for you if you just leave it like the 1st option?

Comment: Yes, it does run perfectly fine.

Comment: Because `SystemParameters.CaptionHeight` isn't an object of type `WindowChrome` and WPF can't implicitly convert it for you.

Comment: Is there a way to make the code one line?

Comment: Declare the WindowChrome as resource (e.g. in Window.Resources), than access it like `Value="{StaticResource MyWindowChrome}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is of type `WindowChrome`, so it expects values of type `WindowChrome`.

In the first case, it happens well. Also, you give to the `WindowChrome` instance a value of the correct type for its property `CaptionHeight`.

In the second case, you're trying to assign to the `WindowChrome` property a value of a totally different type (the type of `CaptionHeight`).

Now, if in your application there is only one single instance of `WindowChrome`, you can declare it as a `StaticResource`:

```
<App.Resources>
  <WindowChrome x:Key="WindowChromeResource"
                CaptionHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}"/>
  </WindowChrome>
</App.Resources>
```

And then call it every time you need:

```
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome"
        Value="{StaticResource WindowChromeResource}"/>
```

If instead you need a dynamic number of different instances, **it's definitely not possible to do this inline**.

Many developers had claimed about the WPF verbosity many times before you, but the WPF team has never improved that aspect. See [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/six-years-of-wpf) and [this](http://www.onemenny.com/blog/xaml-is-verbose-and-probably-will-stay-that-way/) for wider discussion.